# Formula to compare a set of cells and return value

Tags: excel

My formula is

```
{=IFERROR(IF(MAX(IF(N17:$N$32="D",ROW(N17:$N$32)))=
 MIN(IF(ISBLANK(E17:$E$32),ROW(E17:$E$32)))-E17,"D",""),"")}
```

Basically, the rows are delegated to two different types: the parent and the child.

The type shifts if a variable changes in another cell. This formula's purpose is to identify how many rows below it still are child rows, and then (with D being placed in the next cell) determine if the child is complete. If all the children below the parent row are complete, then the current cell should return the value "D".

This formula does currently work... but is only able to identify if the last cell of the children is complete. It does not check what children between it and the parent have any data put in or not.

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(IF(ISERROR(IF(N8:INDIRECT("N"&MIN(IF(ISBLANK(E8:$E$32),ROW(E8:$E$32)))-1)="D",ROW(N8:$N$32))),0,IF(N8:INDIRECT("N"&MIN(IF(ISBLANK(E8:$E$32),ROW(E8:$E$32)))-1)="D",ROW(N8:$N$32))),">0")=MIN(IF(ISBLANK(E8:$E$32),ROW(E8:$E$32)))-E8,"D",""),"")

Newest string. So far it calculates perfectly until it tries to countif ">0". Once it hits that, everything returns as #Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, I changed the angle of attack and have made this formula:

```
{=IF(ISBLANK(C7),"",IF(COUNTIF(N8:INDIRECT("N"&MIN(IF(ISBLANK(N8:$N$98),ROW(N8:$N$98)))),"D")=COUNTA(E8:INDIRECT("E"&MIN(IF(E8:$E$98=0,ROW(E8:$E$98)-1)))),"D",""))}
```

Rather than assigning a value to the cell, it instead decides whether the cell is true or false and then counts base on the number of true's. This will allow me to retain the variable length as well as only assign "D"one if all the cells in question have "D" in them.